Go_router back button just go back to the immediately previous route
I've tried and tried, but go_router and flutter won't do the obvious.
I just want the back button to go back to the immediately previous route that called .go on the current route.
But to no avail:
GoRouter.of(context).pop()
does whatever it wants. Sometimes it goes back to the immediately previous route, other times it goes back to '/'.
I'm using Typed Routes and of course that means that you have to have a / route that goes to basically nothing because it will get called ALWAYS, instead of just when that page is actually routed to.
Here's what I have for routes:
@TypedGoRoute<HomePageRoute>(path: '/', routes: [
  TypedGoRoute<ErrorPageRoute>(path: 'errors/error'),
  TypedGoRoute<LocationServicesErrorRoute>(path: 'errors/location'),
  TypedGoRoute<LoginPageRoute>(path: 'authentication/login'),
  TypedGoRoute<PasswordPageRoute>(path: 'authentication/password'),
  TypedGoRoute<ForgotPasswordPageRoute>(path: 'authentication/forgotpassword'),
  TypedGoRoute<RegistrationRoute>(path: 'registration'),
  TypedGoRoute<SettingsPageRoute>(path: 'settings'),
  TypedGoRoute<RideHomePageRoute>(path: 'ride'),
  TypedGoRoute<RideNowPageRoute>(path: 'ride/now'),
  TypedGoRoute<RideNowSelectDriverPageRoute>(path: 'ride/now/selectdriver'),
  TypedGoRoute<RideLaterPageRoute>(path: 'ride/later'),
  TypedGoRoute<DriverVerificationStatusPageRoute>(path: 'verification/drivers'),
  TypedGoRoute<StartDrivingPageRoute>(
      path: 'verification/drivers/startdriving'),
  TypedGoRoute<GetVerifiedPageRoute>(path: 'verification/riders'),
])
class HomePageRoute extends GoRouteData {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return DefaultHomePage(
      key: state.pageKey,
    );
  }
}

Here's my router:
final router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: navigationKey,
  routes: $appRoutes,
}

I use .go(context) on the routes to navigate to the next screen.
If I actually create a hierarchy in those routes (i.e. the authentication section) with the routes:[] list in stuff, then it NEVER just goes back to the previous route, it ALWAYS goes back to the parent.
How do I stop this madness and get go_router to just do what I think is self evident: when you call pop() it goes back to the immediate previous page that called .go(context) to get there?
(Yes I get that dialogs etc. use this too and subvert this, but I'm not talking about dialogs)
Bonus if I can get it to completely collapse the stack somehow and have ONLY the new typed route in the stack too. (i.e. when I call .go(context) on my home route, I want the entire stack to go away and the only thing in it be the homeroute.

Are you sure you don't want to use .push instead? .go will replace the current route with all the routes leading to the leaf route. Hence .pop behaving that way. go_router is a declarative routing package. From your description, you want an imperative routing behavior.

Ok, see I'm confused by the docs.  .go seems to do something to the history (it shows 2 entries after .go) but it isn't doing what I'm expecting. Does push just add? And if so, push seems to be a generic. What's the value supposed to be?
